# Why is it called LaTeX?

Tags: latex-misc, latex-project

When a person sees the word LaTeX the first time, they are likely to think of a rubber material whose name is simply typed with a weird choice of uppercase letters. This strange name leads to much confusion (even ridiculing) and is thus not the best choice from a branding perspective. Is there a good historical reason why, of all letter combinations you could put in front of TeX, Lamport had to choose La? Because of his own name?

In other words, **why is it called *La*TeX**?

Comment: one suspects that it means Lamport's tex, but Leslie Lamport never confirmed that as far as I know. There was a tradition for joke puns for tex related material "the joy of tex" being the ams tex manual for example.

Comment: You're right, I'm afraid.